# How to cite multiple sources with each different page references?

Tags: latex, biblatex

yes, I have already searched on Google and also here on Stackoverflow, but unfortunately I have not found any suitable results.

I would like to combine several sources with different page references in one citation command in LaTeX.

This is what I've tried so far (MWE):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber, natbib=true, bibstyle=alphabetic, citestyle=alphabetic, sorting=anyt]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{sources.bib}
\begin{document}
\cite[p.1, p.2][p.3, p.4]{A, B}
\end{document}
```

with **sources.bib**

```
@book{A, author = {Bob}, year = {2025}}
@misc{B, author = {Anna}, year = {2024}}
```

The result is `[p.1, p.2 Bob25; Ann24, p.3, p.4]`. I want to have

- several sources,
- that are embraced by squared brackets,
- seperatad with semicolons,
- and, if not empty, have additional information to each source, for page references i.e.

such that: `[Bob25, p.1; Ann24, p.3]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `\cites` macro to cite multiple works at once:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber, natbib=true, bibstyle=alphabetic, citestyle=alphabetic, sorting=anyt]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}

\cites[p.1, p.2]{knuth:ct}[p.3, p.4]{westfahl:space} 

\end{document}
```

[image]